# How do you handle duplicate calls of Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

```
private int limitTime = 10;
void timer() {
    limitTime = 10;
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            stop = false;
            while(!stop) {
                System.out.println("Time >> " + limitTime);
                //Platform.runLater(()->{
                    lbLimitTime.setText(Integer.toString(limitTime));
                    limitTime -= 1;
                //});   
                    if(limitTime < 1) stop = true;
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        };
    };
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start(); 
}
```

We are creating **GUI** programs using **JavaFX**.

I try to set a timer for 10 seconds every time I click.

If the timer function is duplicated by clicking 10 seconds before, the time goes twice as fast.

What part do you think I don't understand?

The timer function is called whenever a click occurs.

When a click occurs, I want to initialize the existing timer and flow normally for 1 second.

Comment: Do you run timer function each time a click occurs in a button for example ?

Comment: Don’t spawn threads uncontrolled. Use an executorservice

Comment: Yes, that's right. When clicked, the function runs and operates normally after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Thread is not a good idea for your use case, use `TimerTask` and `java.util.Timer`

```
// class wide variables
TimerTask timerTask;
Timer timer = new Timer("myTimer");
int limitTimer = 10;

public TimerTask createTask() {
    limitTimer = 10;
    return new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Time>> " + limitTime);
            limitTime--;
            if (limitTime <= 0) {
                cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}

void click() {
   if (timerTask != null) {
      timerTask.cancel();
   }

   timerTask = createTask();
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
}
```

When invoking click method, it'll cancel the old timer and starts a new one.

**Note**: `limitTimer` variable is not thread safe, so if you update it somewhere else, it can lead to strange behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks to you, we solved it easily and you will be very blessed. I think the world is beautiful because there is someone like you.

Comment: @이유진, FYI, avoiding `new Thread(...)` often is a good idea. It can be OK if you do it only when the program starts up, and the thread keeps running for the entire lifetime of the process. But, if you think you want to create a thread to do some simple, finite task (e.g., wait ten seconds and then update a text field,) then there almost always is a better way.